# Get value from disjoint union of data constructors

Tags: haskell

Given this type constructor:

```
data DatabaseItem = DbString String
                  | DbNumber Integer
                  | DbDate   UTCTime
```

I can write a function that unwraps a `DatabaseItem` to, for example, a `UTCTime`:

```
getDate :: DatabaseItem -> Maybe UTCTime
getDate (DbDate a) = Just a
getDate _ = Nothing
```

Rather than write a function like this for each of the 3 data constructors, I want a general function (which also means I don't need the `Maybe` anymore), but I can't quite figure out how to write it. I tried:

```
unwrap :: DatabaseItem -> a
unwrap (i a) = a

-- error: Parse error in pattern: i
```

And:

```
unwrap :: DatabaseItem -> String | Integer | UTCTime
unwrap (DbString a) = a
unwrap (DbDate a) = a
unwrap (DbNumber a) = a

-- error: parse error on input ‘|’
```

Neither compiles. Could someone point out what's wrong with these, and suggest a better implementation? Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like a use case for a prism from lens.

Comment: If `DatabaseItem` was a type-indexed GADT, the last `unwrap` would compile, with type `DatabaseItem a -> a`. But this requires some change to the original data type.

Comment: It’s surprisingly difficult to answer this question without understanding how you use `getDate` and how you would want to use `unwrap`. Even if the second definition of `unwrap` were valid Haskell, the value it produces is no more useful than `DatabaseItem`, since it still can’t be used as a `String`, `Integer`, or `UTCTime` (since it might be any of them). How do you intend to use these functions? What problem are you trying to solve? I’m having trouble understanding that.

Comment: @AlexisKing Here's more complete usage https://gist.github.com/bcherny/b500babe22f75b02a2c424b8d3efe7e2

Comment: @bcherny The question was more about, how do you imagine using `unwrap` once you've implemented it? It's clear how to use the other functions you've already implemented.

Comment: @amalloy `unwrap DbNumber 9001 -- 9001`, or `unwrap DbString "Hello" -- "Hello"`.

Comment: And what type would you give to `unwrap` in that case? It can't be both `DatabaseItem -> Integer` and `DatabaseItem -> String` at the same time, and yet that is how you are hoping to use `unwrap`.

Comment: @amalloy I see. Because `DatabaseItem` is monomorphic, the return type can't be different depending on what concrete type is passed into `unwrap`. Is there a way in Haskell to overload `unwrap`'s signature? eg. in TypeScript you can give unwrap 3 signatures, and the compiler will select the correct one depending on which concrete type the `DatabaseItem` sum type resolved to https://gist.github.com/bcherny/761159d49fb155e9724b841a5a5f479e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Edited:* Added response to comment.

In case you can't figure out why no one is answering your question directly, note that you can write `unwrap` as follows, using `Data.Typeable`:

```
import Data.Maybe
import Data.Time
import Data.Typeable

data DatabaseItem = DbString String
                  | DbNumber Integer
                  | DbDate   UTCTime

unwrap :: (Typeable a) => DatabaseItem -> a
unwrap x = case x of
             DbString x -> go x
             DbNumber x -> go x
             DbDate   x -> go x
  where go :: (Typeable a, Typeable b) => a -> b
        go = fromMaybe (error "unwrap: type mismatch") . cast
```

It can be used like this:

```
> unwrap (DbNumber 1) :: Integer
1
> 1 + unwrap (DbNumber 1)
2
> 1 + unwrap (DbString "foo")
*** Exception: unwrap: type mismatch
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at Unwrap.hs:16:25 in main:Main
>
```

Now, go try to use it in some actual code.  You will find it a largely frustrating experience and realize that either having separate functions, like:

```
getString (DbString x) = Just x
getString _ = Nothing
```

or using a catamorphism or prism will be a much better approach.

In a follow-up comment, you asked why the Haskell version was so much more complicated than the TypeScript version, which doesn't require a cast:

```
type DatabaseItem<T> = { value: T }

let DbString = (value: string) => ({ value })
let DbNumber = (value: number) => ({ value })
let DbDate = (value: Date) => ({ value })

function unwrap<T>({ value }: DatabaseItem<T>) {
  return value
}

unwrap(DbString("Hello")) // "Hello"
unwrap(DbNumber(42)) // 42
unwrap(DbDate(new Date)) // Date
```

As @amalloy noted, your TypeScript example isn't really analogous to the Haskell example we've been discussing.  In the Haskell example, `DbString "Hello"` and `DbNumber 42` have the same type.  In the TypeScript example, `DbString("Hello")` is of type `DatabaseItem<string>` and `DbNumber(42)` is of type `DatabaseItem<number>`.  A Haskell version of this TypeScript code would look more like this, which seems pretty similar in structure to the TypeScript example and doesn't involve any casts:

```
import Data.Time

newtype DatabaseItem a = Item { unwrap :: a }

dbString :: String -> DatabaseItem String
dbString = Item

dbNumber :: (Num a) => a -> DatabaseItem a
dbNumber = Item

dbDate :: UTCTime -> DatabaseItem UTCTime
dbDate = Item

main = do print $ unwrap (dbString "Hello")
          print $ unwrap (dbNumber 42)
          now <- zonedTimeToUTC <$> getZonedTime
          print $ unwrap (dbDate now)
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. Why is this so complicated in Haskell? Eg. in TypeScript there are no casts necessary, because `unwrap`'s argument is structurally typed - if the argument has the expected structure, then the code compiles. https://gist.github.com/bcherny/03297dc849305da2f1aae99501e60f21

Comment: The difference is that in your TypeScript example, you preserve the type information in the type parameter, whereas your Haskell code throws it away. You could as easily write `data DatabaseItem a = Item a`, and then `unwrap (Item 5) == 5` as expected. But if you do this, then values of type DatabaseItem are only useful if you know exactly what their type is: you can't recover that information after building a value. It looks to me like the same would be true in your TypeScript code, but I don't know TypeScript well enough to say for sure.

Comment: As @amalloy notes, your Haskell and TypeScript examples aren't really comparable.  I've added a note to my answer to provide what I think is the Haskell equivalent of your TypeScript example.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response @K.A.Buhr!

Answer (score 5):

A common pattern for user-defined datatypes is to define a catamorphism for them; e.g. in the standard library there are `foldr` for `[]`, `maybe` for `Maybe`, `bool` for `Bool`, `either` for `Either`, and so forth. A catamorphism is essentially a reification of a pattern match into a function, together with a tiny bit of fanciness for recursive types which isn't relevant here.

For your type, it might look like this:

```
databaseItem ::
    (String       -> a) ->
    (Integer      -> a) ->
    (UTCTime      -> a) ->
    (DatabaseItem -> a)
databaseItem string number date item = case item of
    DbString s -> string s
    DbNumber n -> number n
    DbDate   d -> date   d
```

For example, if you wanted to get a string representing the item, you might use:

```
databaseItem id show (formatTime defaultTimeLocale "%c")
    :: DatabaseItem -> String
```

You can also implement your constructor-specific extractors in terms of it.

```
getDate = databaseItem (const Nothing) (const Nothing) Just
```

There is significantly more material on catamorphisms and why they are the Right Choice for consuming ADTs scattered around the web if this piques your interest.

Comment: I think you just made me understand catamorphisms and why they are important.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Daniel's suggestion, but it is worth pointing out that `lens` has the notion of [`Prism`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.4/docs/Control-Lens-Prism.html) which lets you do this too (and much more!). Especially given the gist you link in the comments, this might be interesting

```
{-# Language TemplateHaskell #-}
import Data.Time.Clock
import Control.Lens.TH

data DatabaseItem = DbString String
                  | DbNumber Integer
                  | DbDate   UTCTime

makePrisms ''DatabaseItem
```

This automatically generates `_DbString`, `_DbNumber` and `_DbDate` functions which can easily be adapted inline to do what `getString`, `getNumber`, and `getDate` would do. Namely:

```
main> import Control.Lens
main> :t (^? _DbString)
(^? _DbString) :: DatabaseItem -> Maybe String
main> :t (^? _DbNumber)
(^? _DbNumber) :: DatabaseItem -> Maybe Integer
main> :t (^? _DbDate)
(^? _DbDate) :: DatabaseItem -> Maybe UTCTime
```

However, `lens` is a fair bit more powerful. It can filter through your data base to collect one of the variants in one line too. For example, I can get all the dates in `theDatabase :: [DatabaseItem]` using just `theDatabase ^.. each . _DbDate`.

Comment: Thanks for the concise solution! I've played with lenses in other languages, but need to review them in Haskell.